# Facebook social plugins - commens box

Tags: facebook-comments

Facebook social plugins - commens box is not showing up in wordpress any solution Now I am doing it by generating code not through plugins

I am generating code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

app id and everything is correct

it was not working before

Comment: Please explain your problem and show us what you have tried

Comment: Check your plugin settings, your app id etc included at appropriate places? is it working before? provide more detailed information regarding this.

Comment: no error and nothing is displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a comment box on a simple html page and it is working

```
  http://gigyonline.com/test.html
```

Please try with a simple html page and if it working verify the browser you are using. You can see the view source of the above page. It has only the facebook plugin code.